# Lining Up Submenu With Menu

Tags: html, css

I'm still relatively new to coding, so this is probably an easy fix.
I have set up menu with 5 menu items, and submenu items under two of the primary menu items. If I line up the first submenu with its menu item, the second one is too far right. If I line up the second submenu with its menu item, the first one is too far right. Is there a way to make both submenus line up under their respective menu items?

Here is the HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="http://kerryaltmantest.info">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://kerryaltmantest.info/aboutme.html">About Me</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://kerryaltmantest.info/fpa.html">Fairfax Psychological Associates</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://kerryaltmantest.info/credentials.html">Credentials</a></li>
        </ul></li>
    <li><a href="http://kerryaltmantest.info/publications.html">Publications</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://kerryaltmantest.info/w5m.html">The Wisdom of the Five Messengers</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://kerryaltmantest.info/otherpublications.html">Other Publications</a></li>
        </ul></li>
    <li><a href="http://kerryaltmantest.info/location.html">Location</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://kerryaltmantest.info/strategicinteractions.html">Strategic Interactions</a></li>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
    #menu {
width: 950px;
height:35px;
font-size: 20px;
font-family: cambria, Georgia, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
background-color: #FFF;
border-radius: 0px;
margin-top: -175px;
margin-left: 25px;
}

#menu li {
display: inline;
padding: 10px;
}

#menu a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #2B297F;
padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

#menu a:hover {
color: #2B297F;
background-color: #999;
}

#menu li ul
{font-size:15px;
margin-left:-160px;
margin-top:25px;
position:absolute;
text-align:left;
display:none;} 

#menu li:hover ul
{display:inline-block;
 }

#menu li li
{list-style:none; display:list-item;}

#menu li li a
{color:#2B297F; text-decoration:none;white-space:nowrap;
}

#menu li li a:hover
{color:#2B297F; background-color: #999 text-decoration:none;}
```

The site is at http://kerryaltmantest.info if you want to see what I mean about the submenu. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few changes in css that need to be made:

```
#menu li ul {
    font-size: 15px;
    /* margin-left: -160px; REMOVE */
    /* margin-top: 25px; REMOVE */
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    top: 30px; /* add this */
    left: 0; /* add this */
    padding: 0 /* add this */
    display: none;
}

#menu li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative; /* add this */
}
```

The biggest reason that the `ul` is not positioning properly is because the `li` it is contained in did not have a position style set. When this happens, absolutely-positioned elements are positioned according to the first ancestor that has a position type set. Additionally, that was apparently not coming into effect because no positioning rules (`top/left/bottom/right`) were set in the `ul`. Adding these two things and resetting the margins/padding fixed the issue (css is directly editable/debuggable in chrome's debugger).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position:

> Absolute positioning
>
> Elements that are positioned relatively are still considered to be in
>   the normal flow of elements in the document. In contrast, an element
>   that is positioned absolutely is taken out of the flow and thus takes
>   up no space when placing other elements. The absolutely positioned
>   element is positioned relative to nearest positioned ancestor. If a
>   positioned ancestor doesn't exist, the initial container is used.

Chrome debugging information: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/index

Comment: Check this rule, you missed a semicolon: #menu li ul { /*...*/ padding: 0 display:none; }

Comment: Fixed it completely, and thank you for the extra info so I don't make that mistake again!! Thank you!!

Comment: Sorry, deleted that first comment, lol, because I realized my very dumb error ;)